# website error after change apache port

Tags: apache, web, webserver, apache2, port

I need to change the apache port to my site, I tried putting in port.conf listen 8080 (instead of 80) and NameVirtualHost *: 8010 (instead of 80), regarding the 000default.conf I set  (again instead of 80) but now when I open my site: xxxx.ddns.net I get nothing and the site appears to me only if I specify the port, putting xxxx.ddns.net: 8010, how can I change the port and ensure that the site appears without the need to specify the port?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I don't understand why 8010 and 8080 aren't the identical port and obviously default.conf should not be overriden...

Port Redirection is a job for your Firewall/NAT (FritzBox?). A browser will always try to connect to port 80 and the NAT will redirect it to port 8080 (8010?) in your local network.

Comment: i need a different port, i need the port 80 for another thing.. anyway, is possible to say to the browser that when open the website, it read on a personalized port?

Comment: No thats not possible. Using port 80 for anything else then unencrypted http traffic is everything else then good style.You could use another machine and redirect your subdomain to it. Maybe with virtualization if you have multiple ip addresses available.